# Error publishing data to Kafka topic using Spring

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, avro

I am trying to publish data to a Kafka topic using Kafka Template of spring.
As soon as the code reaches the send method of kafka template,

```
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Data>> future = this.kafkaTemplate.send(topic, data);
```

it throws an error :

```
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: null
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:151)
        at org.apache.avro.io.DirectBinaryEncoder.writeFixed(DirectBinaryEncoder.java:124)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeFixed(GenericDatumWriter.java:339)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:147)
        at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeField(SpecificDatumWriter.java:98)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:195)
        at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeRecord(SpecificDatumWriter.java:83)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:130)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:82)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:72)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:101)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:902)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:862)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:781)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:562)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:363)
```

There's no other error and I am unable to figure out why is this happening. The schema registry is present.

Data class is generated using Avro which contains two attributes: one of type RawId, another String.

Is there a way to solve this out?

Comment: can you add more information about `SendResult` and `Data` class implementation?

Comment: SendResult class is internal to Spring Kafka. Data class is my custom class wiht two attributes ; one of type RawId, another String. I will add hte details.

Comment: if using kafka template, you should define serialize for producer factory. You can show your configuation?